# Can`t deploy click package

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages, porting

I port qt application on Ubuntu Touch 
Build is ok
Click package created
But when sdk start application i get this:

```
Установленный chebfmchat.neochapay-0.1.armhf (installed:click,removable=1,app_name=chat)
Sdk-Launcher> Application installed successfully
Sdk-Launcher> AppId:                   chebfmchat.neochapay_chat_0.1
Sdk-Launcher> Architecture:            armhf
Sdk-Launcher> Application confined:    True
Sdk-Launcher> Communication directory: /home/phablet/.local/share/chebfmchat.neochapay/
Sdk-Launcher> Application started: 6713
Debug-helper> Setting up environment
Debug-helper> TmpDir:      /home/phablet/.local/share/chebfmchat.neochapay/
Debug-helper> AppId:       chebfmchat.neochapay_chat_0.1
Debug-helper> Environment: confined
Debug-helper> Executable was not found in the PATH
Sdk-Launcher> Received a failed event
Sdk-Launcher> The Application exited, cleaning up
Sdk-Launcher> Finished
```

Comment: It can't find the executable. Is Exec parameter in *.desktop file correct?

Comment: `[Desktop Entry]
Name=chat
Exec=chat
Icon=chat/chat.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
`

Comment: Try to start from a clean project template and work out the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exec=opt/chat/bin/chat 
1 chat - name of application. 2 chat is target of pro file...

It`s ugly but it work/